# Changing argument in MethodCallExpression

Tags: c#, iqueryable, linq-expressions

I have an expression query which is targeted to `IQueryable<WebMessageDto>`.
In my expression visitor I'm replacing queryable source to `IQueryable<WebMessage>`.
When query executes I'm getting exception:

> Expression of type 'WebMessage' cannot be used for parameter of type 'WebMessageDto' of method 'Int32 Count[WebMessageDto](WebMessageDto])'

Can I replace class types in this expression?
`WebMessage` and `WebMessageDto` have the same fields.

The idea is to handle query to WebMessageDto, execute it on WebMessage DataSource, then convert result to WebMessageDto and return it.

I've tried to change Arguments in MethodCallExpression but I got exceptions...

```
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Method.Name == "Count")
        {
            //Expression.Convert(node.Arguments[0], typeof(WebMessage));

            //List<ConstantExpression> newArgs = new List<ConstantExpression>()
            //{
            //    Expression.Constant(typeof(WebMessage)
            //};
            //
            //node.Update(node.Object, newArgs);
        }

        return node;
    }
```

Comment: So, node.Arguments[0] is of type WebMessageDto?

Comment: @Markus yes it is. and I thing the whole query is targeted to `WebMessageDto`...

Comment: Do you have a type converter defined that knows how to convert between WebMessage and WebMessageDto?

Comment: @Markus nope, do you have any examples?

Comment: http://cyotek.com/blog/creating-a-custom-typeconverter-part-1 - there are quite a number of them. I am not sure they will work for you, because I lack experience with overloading VisitMethodCall. It's something that I would try, though.

Comment: A `TypeConverter` is not relevant to the question here. You need at least to: first, replace the `IQueryable<WebMessageDto>` object with an `IQueryable<WebMessage>` in the method call; second, replace the original `ParameterExpression` in `LambdaExpression.Arguments` and `LambdaExpression.Body` with a `ParameterExpression` of type `WebMessage` (e.g. with another visitor); third, if the returned value is dependent on the element type, then you have to convert the returned values back from `WebMessage` to `WebMessageDto`. In any case, you need to know how complex the supported queries can be.